# How to proper search for a string inside a dir

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

How do I search for a specific string inside a dir (folder)?

ChatGPT suggested this, but I am concerned about IO usage and if it will lead to performance issue and cause the server either crash or take really long time to respond. It is being used when a user creates an account, it should look for existing account using that email. It should first get all the email fields in all the files. Then it should decrypt them all. Lastly it should it compare a string (provided email) and tell if there is a file that has that particular email.

`const fs = require('fs');`

`const path = require('path');`

`function searchInDirectory(directoryPath, searchString) {`

`fs.readdir(directoryPath, (err, files) => {`

`if (err) {`

`console.error(err);`

`return;`

`}`

`files.forEach(file => {`

`const filePath = path.join(directoryPath, file);`

`fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, content) => {`

`if (err) {`

`console.error(err);`

`return;`

`}`

`if (content.includes(searchString)) {`

`console.log(\`Found "${searchString}" in file: ${file}`);`

`}`

`});`

`});`

`});`

`}`

`const directoryToSearch = './path/to/your/directory';`

`const searchString = 'your-search-string';`

`searchInDirectory(directoryToSearch, searchString);`

For context my file system look like this
./db/users/users

randomUserId1.json

randomUserId2.json

randomUserId3.json

​

Inside the user files it is like this
{email: "encryptedText-Initialization_vector"}

like {email: de49c16ee480589336a2db414329669bea52022f2ed90d277b8952a6f888f581-2476bad028e05a950391b3cea852629c}